Units of time variable in downloaded netCDF file are not compatible with the request code in ERA5 reanalysis data
I put my request to download the required data from the below Dataset of the ERA5 reanalysis
ERA5 hourly data on single levels from 1940 to present
In the downloaded .nc file, when I read it in the Anaconda Spyder, I observed that units of time variable are confusing....Units are in seconds and the year starts from 1970 whereas I requested the data for the month of June of the year 2024!!!
how do I solve this mismatch. In my understanding its due to selected calendar. I have no idea, how to address this issue?
Below was the request code:
import cdsapi

dataset = "reanalysis-era5-single-levels"
request = {
'product_type': \['reanalysis'\],
'variable': \['10m_u_component_of_wind', '10m_v_component_of_wind'\],
'year': \['2024'\],
'month': \['06'\],
'day': \['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14',      '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30'\],
'time': \['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00',  '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00',   '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'\],
'data_format': 'netcdf',
'download_format': 'unarchived',
'area': \[38, 61, 23, 81\]
}

client = cdsapi.Client()
client.retrieve(dataset, request).download()

Below is the description of time variable when I explore it in Anaconda-Spyder.
\<class 'netCDF4.\_netCDF4.Variable'\>
int64 valid_time(valid_time)
long_name: time
standard_name: time
units: seconds since 1970-01-01
calendar: proleptic_gregorian
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (720,)
filling off

valid_time.dimensions
Out\[88\]: ('valid_time',)

valid_time.units
Out\[89\]: 'seconds since 1970-01-01'


I will provide a code snippet see if that works, I have asked you to provide the data which helps.

hi, this is standard - the date you are looking at is the base time, and the time index is in units of "seconds from" that base time date - if you do "ncdump -v,time file.nc" you will see the time variable does not start from zero but instead a large number which is the number of seconds between 1970 and your date in 2024.  If you do "cdo showdate file.nc" you will see that the dates are correct, I am sure.

You can try this code snippet see if that works for you.
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Load your NetCDF file
ds = nc.Dataset('your_file.nc')

# Access the time variable
time_var = ds.variables['valid_time']

# Convert the time units to datetime objects
time_units = time_var.units
calendar = time_var.calendar if hasattr(time_var, 'calendar') else 'standard'
time_values = nc.num2date(time_var[:], units=time_units, calendar=calendar)

# Print the converted dates
print(time_values)

